# Removing node from graph and all of its edges

Tags: c++, graph

Could someone explain me which input is right to make the remove-function work and also explain me why.

```
void Graph::remove(Node& rNode)
    {

        for (std::list<Edge*>::iterator it = rNode.getOutEdges().begin(); it != rNode.getOutEdges().end(); it++) {
            remove(*it); //thats not working
        }
        m_nodes.remove(&rNode);
        delete &rNode;
    }

    void Graph::remove(Edge& rEdge)
    std::list<Edge*>& getOutEdges() { return m_outgoingEdges; }
```

Comment: "_Could someone explain for me_" No. No one can explain for you, because It is not clear what you are asking for and not enough info provided.

Comment: what is not clear. the input for the remove funtion throws an error and im asking what would be the right thing to write there because what i put there is not correct.

Comment: Cool. What is the error? Where? By _input_ do you mean the parameter `rNode` or `*it`? Are they the same? And your snippet code can't be compiled. Please post [MCVE]

Comment: by parameter i mean the iterator **it** in the remove function. below i posted what the remove funtion takes as an input and what getOutEdges returns. and visual studio says that there are no funtions which takes this parameter as input.

Comment: if u need more more information tell me